# Heroku Delayed Job error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job, worker

Google wasn't very helpful on this one, so I was hoping someone here might have an idea.

My app works fine on server (and was recently working fine on heroku), but an hour or so ago, when I went to open a certain page on it (one that involves displaying information that is affected by a delayed_job I have running), I got a heroku error, and the logs say (among many other things):

```
dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms service=119ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-11-07T23:17:44+00:00 app[worker.1]:    (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, priority AS priority FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE (run_at < '2012-11-07 23:17:44.830238' and failed_at is NULL) GROUP BY priority
2012-11-07T23:17:44+00:00 app[worker.1]:    (2.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE (failed_at is not NULL)
2012-11-07T23:17:44+00:00 app[worker.1]:    (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE (locked_by is not NULL)
```

Obviously, a problem with the delayed_job, but I'm not sure where to start looking, particularly considering how it was working before and still functions on my server.

Any ideas what the problem is or how to start debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely in the job that's being process in DJ, which may not inject an error message into your log. You can search your log for specific worker messages and try to see the error. Problem with even do this is that you need to ascertain when the job will be running, or else you might be looking in the wrong part of your logs.

```
heroku run logs || grep worker
```

Secondly, you need to figure out why your view rendered an error. Since your view is rendered by your app, and not your worker, something is out of sync in your app. Figure out exactly what is wrong, and that may point to what your worker did/did not do.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, it's "heroku logs || grep worker" (without the "run"). It's definitely providing me with more data to work with, so hopefully I can figure this one out.